# how to prevent unnecessary renders in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I will explain with comments in code

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
function TableComponent(props){
      const checkboxSearch = () => {
      let tempVar = [[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[4,5,6]];
      //containerID = index of chosen array
      const container = document.getElementById("optionsContainer_"+containerID);
      
      if (searchValue === " ") {
        setUniques(props.unique);
      }
      
      const results = props.unique[containerID].filter((item) => {
        if (item) {
          if (typeof item !== "number") {
            return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase()) > -1;
          } else {
            return (
              item.toString().indexOf(searchValue.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1
            );
          }
        }
        return null;
      });

      tempVar[containerID] = results;
      setUniques(tempVar);
      };



return(
uniques.map((item,index) => {
  <child data={item} key={index}/>
})

}
```

and now child component:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
function TableHead(props) {

  return (
    <div id={props.keys[props.index]} className="optionsContainer">
          {props.unique.map((item, key) => {
            return (
          <label key={key}>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value={item ? item : "empty"}
            />
              <p>
                {item.toFixed(2)}
              </p>
          </label>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

when one of the arrays element changes it re-renders everything again, and I have more then 40k data and I'm using this method **on input event listener** so its really slow... any suggestions how to handle this?

Comment: You could use `PureComponent` or its' hook implementation in `recompose`, where you check in every child if their props have changed or convert your dimensional array to a map and use `useMemo` to check if single dimensions have changed

Comment: You should use some kind of item ID, like `key={ item.id }` instead of `key={ index }`. If you don't have an ID, maybe you can "invent" one on the first render. If even that is not possible, i.e. everything might change at any time, then you need to compare everything on every render, to find any changes.